# How do i open and create a file like this?

Tags: php, javascript, html

Well,my current situation is like this.

When i search something on my site for ex. `http://example.org/web-search.phtml?search=SEARCHED+TEXT` the respective content is shown.

As you can see I'm using a `GET` form to get the data from the previous form.So the first thing i want to do is open a file with the same as `SEARCHED+TEXT`.So now i want to open and save file in

```
http://example.org/web-search/SEARCHED+TEXT.html
```

So each time a person searches a page like  `http://example.org/web-search.phtml?search=SEARCHED+TEXT` a respective `.html` file should be created in the respective folder

And no.2

Now i want the whole source of http://example.org/web-search.phtml?search=SEARCHED+TEXT to be copied into `http://example.org/web-search/SEARCHED+TEXT.html`

So how do i do this ?

NOTE: If i copy the whole source including the code for copying and creating file then each time the person creates `http://example.org/web-search/SEARCHED+TEXT.html` a new HTML file will be Opened..

So i hope you got my BIG BIG question !!

**I'm not saving the results.I'm just saving the iframe source.So technically its not static**

Comment: I'm slightly confused here. From what you're saying, it sounds like you want to create a cache for a search engine? I understand that you want to create the file `SEARCHED+TEXT.html`, but I don't understand what "source" you want to copy into it. What are you searching FOR with this script? Are you searching within your own website, or are you searching Google?

Comment: You're doing it wrong.  Very wrong

Comment: What source are you talk about? You want to save PHP source code in a file? Why is the question tagged JavaScript? The whole problem is very confusing....

Comment: The thing is the source just has Iframe so its not exactly caching the pages.I just want to keep a separate page for each page search

Comment: I have modified the ques.Its more clear now.How about now ?

Comment: I sort of understand now. You have a "search engine" which is essentially made up of several iframes, each pointing to popular search engines. What I don't understand is why you want to cache the search results. If you searched for "facebook" in 2001, you wouldn't have seen much. Now it's the top hit. Since the results are changing, you're just wasting time and server space by saving anything.

Comment: I've replaced spam url with example.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `file_put_contents()` and the `$_GET` to do the operations you want.

Firstly you can get the filename of the file by calling :

```
$filename = $_GET['search'] . '.html';
```

That would return your value, `SEARCHED+TEXT`

Secondly you can use `file_put_contents($filename, $some_source_content)` to create the file.

Comment: "file_put_contents($filename, $some_source_content)"

Comment: make this "$some_source_content" ?

Comment: be careful with this.  Make sure you sanitize $filename else some one can do something like:  http://searchr.us/web-search.phtml?search=%2Fproc%2Fsys%2Fkernel%2Fcore_pattern which would write to some core files.

Comment: But i have remove HTML tags !!

Comment: is my site vulnerable to it ? http://searchr.us/web-search.phtml?search=%2Fproc%2Fsys%2Fkernel%2Fcore_pattern

Answer (score 0):

What i think you want to do is use apache mod_rewrite, you point anything from /web-search/(.*).html to some php file on your server (search.php) and use that PHP file to render all of your searches.  This will give you the dynamics you want without creating a billion flat files on your server for no good reason.

Comment: Misunderstood the question. He already has a dynamic solution. `http://searchr.us/web-search.phtml?search=SEARCHED+TEXT`. What he's looking for is a way to cache the results of the dynamic solution.